# How to create the credential for Watson Machine Learning API to save a ML model

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

```
from watson_machine_learning_client import WatsonMachineLearningAPIClient
wml_credentials = {
    "apikey" : "*****", # my own api key
    "url"    : "https://jp-tok.ml.cloud.ibm.com"
}
client = WatsonMachineLearningAPIClient( wml_credentials )
```

I coded the exact same thing according to http://ibm-wml-api-pyclient.mybluemix.net/?_ga=2.133579662.1462677150.1614734898-1588850442.1613548438, the subtopic: Authentication, to create an instance of Watson Machine Learning python client to save a ML model.

But I received an error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-513e37fb8d9f> in <module>
      4     "url"    : "https://jp-tok.ml.cloud.ibm.com"
      5 }
----> 6 client = WatsonMachineLearningAPIClient( wml_credentials )

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/watson_machine_learning_client/client.py in __init__(self, wml_credentials, project_id)
     40         if wml_credentials is None:
     41             raise NoWMLCredentialsProvided()
---> 42         if 'icp' == wml_credentials[u'instance_id'].lower():
     43             self.ICP = True
     44             os.environ["DEPLOYMENT_PLATFORM"] = "private"

KeyError: 'instance_id'
```

What can I do to solve this problem? The content on the web states that

> Note: There is no instance_id to be provided. instance_id will be
> picked up from associated space/project for the new(v2) instance
> plans.

Comment: The docs say "APIClient", your example "WatsonMachineLearningAPIClient". Why? Is that all code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the deprecated version of the WML Python client in your code.
Import the [latest package](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-watson-machine-learning/):

```
from ibm_watson_machine_learning import APIClient
```

Also, use the new **APIClient** object in place of the deprecated **WatsonMachineLearningClient**:

```
wml_credentials = {
    "apikey": "<your_wml_apikey>",
    "url": "<your_wml_endpoint_url>"
}
client = APIClient(wml_credentials)
```